# How to send a magic packet from OS X in order to wake a PC on the LAN? (WOL)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, wake-on-lan

Either some (preferably free/OS) app or a command line tool will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [WakeOnLan](http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan) or [wol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wake-on-lan) — both are open source, both are available through MacPorts (and possibly through Homebrew as well).

Comment: WakeOnLan appears to no longer be available - the readpixel.com site linked above is being flagged as malware by Chrome, and it was also recently removed from homebrew-cask - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/104849. I'd recommend using the open-source perl script from the homebrew formula in the answer below.

Answer (score 19):

Install the [wakeonlan](https://github.com/jpoliv/wakeonlan) package using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

`$ brew install wakeonlan`

(It's a Perl script for waking up computers via Wake-On-LAN magic packets.)

When installed, you can send a "magic packet" from your Terminal to any device using its IP (Internet Protocol) and MAC (Media Access Control) address.

Here's an example of a typical use:

`$ wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 -p 1234 01:02:03:04:05:06`

The scripts takes 2 arguments, the MAC address of the NIC, and an IP address.

> Note: The IP address argument is tricky and isn't what you'd think.
>
> For a NIC on your local subnet, use the broadcast-address of this subnet. (e.g. subnet 192.168.10.0 with netmask 255.255.255.0, use 192.168.10.255)

For example, I have a Synology NAS manually configured with the IP address of `10.0.1.100` with a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` and a router address of `10.0.1.1`.

**The correct IP address to use is *not that of the device*, but instead the *broadcast-address of the subnet*.**

Continuing on my example, I used the following command to successfully wake up my Synology:

`$ wakeonlan -i 10.0.1.255 -p 7 01:02:03:04:05:06`

*(Naturally, substitute the actual values of your device and network for your situation.)*

You can get more information from the wakeonlan man page, `man makeonlan`, or a quick glossary of commands from `wakeonlan -h`.

Comment: Just a slight hint: looks like the command has three parameters, for -i the broadcast address (not the IP address), for -p the magic packet (which you do not explain, looks like you are showing 1234 or 7 as magic packet) and third parameter is the Ethernet (or MAC-) address.

Comment: @pebwindkraft , `-p` sets the destination port, actually (and defaults to 9).

Comment: FWIW, straight out of the box this worked for me to wake an Intel NUC using just `wakeonlan 94:c6:91:a1:68:22`. No parameters necessary. To be fair, the NUC is on my home LAN and I got the MAC address by running `arp -a` and recognising the IP address, so obviously the ARP table was still valid.

Comment: Like @HeathRaftery, I experienced the same — no need for any extra parameters. It actually makes some sense: on most LANs, you just need to broadcast on the segment where you are. The only reason for having this extra `-i` option is if you've got a router or bridge or similar multi-networked device, and have to specify in advance _which_ device/network to use...

Answer (score 0):

## install:

```
# create a binary dir (-p, avoids error if dir exists)
mkdir -p $HOME/bin 
# download the script
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpoliv/wakeonlan/master/wakeonlan -o ~/bin/wakeonlan
# give execution permission 
chmod +x ~/bin/wakeonlan
```

## wake:

```
~/bin/wakeonlan THE_MAC_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain what these commands do?

Comment: mkdir: make ad new directory; curl: Download "wakeonlan"; ~/bin/wakeonlan: execute the downloaded script.